SMD marking code L41 SOT-23-6
Please help me find the part number for the IC with marking "L41" sot-23-6.


It's a Panjit BAT54DW Schottky diode array. The package is SOT363 and not SOT23-6, I confirmed from your picture using the XTR300 as scale.

Can't find a picture of the BAT54DW, but here is one from LCSC of the BAT54SDW with the marking code L44. The marking style matches.


Merci infiniment ça me aidera bien,
MES SALUTATIONS
